# Nested form in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, nested-forms, activeadmin

I need help!
I have 2 models for a Survey:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :poll_questions, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:text].blank?    }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

There is model for questions as follows: (it seems these assocciations are correct)

```
class PollQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :poll
has_many :poll_answers, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:text].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

In addition in active Admin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Poll do
form do |f|
f.inputs "Main poll" do
  f.input :title
  f.input :description
end

f.inputs do
f.has_many :poll_questions do |question|
  question.input :text
end
end

f.buttons
end

end
```

It has a beautiful form that doesnt create an actual question object! why?
I've tried my best to solve the problem, but I've failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you've got a double level for accepts_nested_attributes_for. Why not create a new model for Poll responses which has many Poll answers?

You would then set up an accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_answers within the PollResponse class.

Then you can not only sort your form problems out, but also track who answered the poll (potentially) and when the poll response was created. The PollResponses model would also have to belong to Polls to differentiate which Poll was being answered.

Comment: and what about creating answer variants? from admin panel?

Comment: doesn`t it work? [Ryan`s Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) with active admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating object,

```
f.has_many :poll_questions, PollQuestion.new do |question|
  question.input :text
end
```